# 4 Color Theorem - What am I not seeing??

Tags: geometry, coloring

Let me say first that I am in no way a mathematician. Just slightly interested in mathematics. I think I may have found an exception to the 4 color theorem.
I don't claim to be smarter than those who proved the theorem, and I'll assume I'm wrong.
What am I missing here?
(forgive my quickly drawn graph!)[image: 5 color map?]

(I created this account just to ask this question, so the website made me embed the image instead of just adding it straight to the question.)

I may be missing some fundamental rule in setting up my problem. But I think my map fits the desired intent of the "map" motif of the theorems original question.

Comment: The green regions may be recolored red and purple.

Comment: You can make the green pieces either red or purple. You don't need green.

Comment: You've missed something indeed, and all those who wrote that monumental paper , and the computer which went through all those combinations ,are breathing a collective sigh of relief! But yes, the number of upvotes shows : it was not easy!

Comment: In brief, the fact that you chose to use green for all three of those wedges does not mean they must all be the same color. The four-coloring does not make them the same color.

Comment: Free software at [__Four Colour Problem__](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/fcp/index.htm)

Comment: Since the theorem says that any map _can_ be coloured with four colours, you should really have tried to **prove** that your map _cannot_ (not just that it _can_ be coloured with five). By doing that you might have learnt more about the problem and/or your thought processes than you did by waiting for other people to disprove that claim. What made you think it was not possible (or did you not understand what the theorem says)?

Answer (score 18):

Here is your map colored with only four colours.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I've put numbers instead of colours (I left yours because whatever).

[image]

Comment: You have used 5 colors instead of 4.

Comment: @NitinUniyal If I had, I'm pretty sure I would have written a $5$ somewhere, which I did not.

Comment: @NitinUniyal The colors are from the picture linked in the question, so ignore them if they're confusing you.  The numbers represent the new 4-coloring

Comment: You color code map is not bijective.

Comment: oh...ok. I understood now. You superimposed your answer on the OP's attempt.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you looked at it for long enough. By the way, you will *not* fault the theorem, it is *proven*.

[image]